# TCPDUMP w/SNAT Configuration Shows Private IP on ICMP Reply

Tags: networking, iptables, nat, netfilter

Problem: TCPDUMP icmp reply inexplicably has the private address.  I would expect it to have the public address.

```
[router.box(1.2.3.4)]$ tcpdump -n -i br1 icmp
10:42:21.689215 IP 1.2.3.4 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 2935, seq 1, length 64
10:42:21.696828 IP 8.8.8.8 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 2935, seq 1, length 64
```

I have configured my linux box to perform SNAT on packets leaving bridge interface `br1`:

```
[router.box(1.2.3.4)]$ iptables -t nat -L -n -v
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 75970 packets, 4560K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                   
   62  3816 SNAT       all  --  *      br1     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            to:1.2.3.4
```

The outgoing icmp packet correctly has it's source address changed from `10.0.0.1` to `1.2.3.4`, But the icmp reply packet shows as already being translated to the private address (`10.0.0.1`):

```
[local.box(10.0.0.1)]$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=112 time=8.06 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=112 time=7.97 ms
```

```
[router.box(1.2.3.4)]$ tcpdump -n -i br1 icmp
10:42:21.689215 IP 1.2.3.4 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 2935, seq 1, length 64
10:42:21.696828 IP 8.8.8.8 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 2935, seq 1, length 64
```

My network configurations are as follows:

```
[router.box(1.2.3.4)]$ ip a
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br1 state UP group default qlen 1000
36: br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
  inet 1.2.3.4/26 ...
36: br3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
  inet 10.0.0.2/24 ...
```

```
[router.box(1.2.3.4)]$ ip route
default via <gateway address> dev br1
10.0.0.1/24 dev br3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2
```

```
[local.box(10.0.0.1)]$ ip a
36: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
  inet 10.0.0.1/24 ...
```

```
[local.box(10.0.0.1)]$ ip route
default via 10.0.0.2 dev eno1
```

Am I misunderstanding where TCPDUMP collects its packets from?  Is it after the address has been translated back to the source address?

**EDIT:**
It looks like tcpdump on the physical interface (`eno2`) produces the expected result:

```
[router.box(1.2.3.4)]$ sudo tcpdump -n -i eno2 icmp                                                                                                                 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eno2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:33:49.331086 IP 1.2.3.4 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3011, seq 1, length 64
13:33:49.338641 IP 8.8.8.8 > 1.2.3.4: ICMP echo reply, id 3011, seq 1, length 64
```

So does SNAT get applied after it enters the physical interface (`eno2`) and before the bridge interface (`br1`)?

Comment: Very weird... but to the best of my knowledge, tcpdump will show what is _physically_ landing on the network interface. Is it possible that the gateway is using that IP _for real_ when sending traffic to your router? What happens if you try pinging 8.8.8.8 from the router?

Comment: Hmmm, not quite sure how I would show what is physically landing on the interface...maybe tcpdump on the eth0 instead of the bridge?

Comment: Updated post to reflect tcpdump on the physical interface and not the bridge...

Comment: Are you using Docker? Anyway try this: `rmmod br_netfilter` .

Answer (score 0):

This a normal behavior. If you want to see the pre-NATed and post-NATed IP, replace the interface with "any"

```
sudo tcpdump -eni any icmp
```